# Rollup start timestamp of my bash script to every monday morning 7 AM PST of the current week

Tags: timestamp, rollup

I have a bash script which contains some API's which is taking start & end timestamps.
So my requirement is to rollup every week
Start Timestamp : Should always points to current week monday 7 AM PST (This should be in Timestamp.. Ex : 1596463200)
End Timestamp : Should always points to current week sunday 11: 59 PM PST (This should be in Timestamp.. Ex : 1597042740)

Can any one guide me how i can rollup
start timestamps to current week monday and end timestamp to current week sunday.

My bash script looks like this

> cat abc.sh

```
makeAPICall() {
    curl -X GET $1 > $2
    chmod 755 $2

        if [[ $(find $2 -type f -size +100c 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
            cp -R $2 /app/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/webapps/WFSReportUI/$2
            chmod 755 /app/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/webapps/WFSReportUI/$2
        fi
}
endts=`date +%s`
startTs=`date -dmonday +%s`
#startTs=`date -dlast-monday +%s`
makeAPICall "localhost:8080/wsaas-report-app/services/fulfillmentReport/wfsExternalSellers?startTimestamp=$startTs&endTimestamp=$endts&isLastweekReport=false" "WFSCustomerOrderSummary.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following adaptions

```
startTs=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" monday + 7 hours' +%s`
endts=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" next monday - 1 minute' +%s`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. endTimestamp working as expected... but startTimeStamp showing as next monday timestamp. but i want from current monday. that means 08/03/2020 - 08/09/202

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. I have modified start & end timestamps like the following and both are working absolutely fine.  


startTs=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" last sunday + 31 hours' +%s`
endts=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" next monday - 1 minute' +%s`

Answer (score 0):

@hacfi : Thank you very much for the idea. I have modified start & end timestamps like the following and both are working absolutely fine.

```
startTs=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" last sunday + 31 hours' +%s`
endts=`date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" next monday - 1 minute' +%s`
```